# LEB128 in Haskell

Tags: beginner, haskell, integer, bitwise, serialization

I have implemented the [LEB128](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LEB128) encoding for unsigned integers. I'm fairly new to Haskell so I have some doubt about the coding style I'm using, particularly the definition of `byte` and then 2 lines later `byte'`:

```
import Data.Bits
import Data.Word

uleb128 :: Integer -> [Word8]
uleb128 0 = []
uleb128 n =
  let byte = (fromIntegral n :: Word8) .&. 0x7F
      n' = shiftR n 7
      byte' = if n' == 0
              then byte
              else (byte .|. 0x80)
  in
    byte' : uleb128 n'
```

Futhermore I have doubts about the choice of `let .. in` in favor of `... where` and the use of `if then else` vs `case of`. I'm very much still learning Haskell so I'm curious how a seasoned Haskell programmer would have written the above function.

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! Nice first question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `uleb128` doesn't follow the LEB128 format, since `0` isn't encoded as a single byte:

```
uleb128 0 `shouldBe` [0x00]
```

With this in mind, we have to rewrite `uleb128`:

```
uleb128 :: Integer -> [Word8]
uleb128 n
  | n' == 0   = [byte]
  | otherwise = (byte .|. 0x80) : uleb128 n'
  where
    byte = fromIntegral (n .&. 0x7F)
    n'   = n `shiftR` 7
```

Or, to write it with `let…in…` and `if`:

```
uleb128 n = 
  let byte = fromIntegral (n .&. 0x7F)
      n'   = n `shiftR` 7
  in 
    if n' == 0
      then [byte]
      else (byte .|. 0x80) : uleb128 n'
```

It's a personal preference whether you use `where` or `let`. I usually prefer `where`, since it works great with guards.

Note that neither of these versions check whether `n` is actually non-negative. Unfortunately, there is no `Natural` type in base. Depending on your use case, you can use `ErrorType [Word8]` or `error`, although the first is usually preferred (with `ErrorType = Maybe` or `ErrorType = Either String`).

An alternative that doesn't exploit the bits behind the number can be achieved with `quotRem`, where `case` is rather handy:

```
uleb128' :: Integer -> [Word8]
uleb128' n = case n `quotRem` 128 of
  (0, r) -> [fromIntegral r]
  (q, r) -> (fromIntegral r + 128) : uleb128' q
```

We can use [QuickCheck](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/QuickCheck-2.8.1) to verify that both work the same:

```
ghci> let largeInt = choose (10^4, 10^10) -- to generate large Integers
ghci> quickCheck $ forAll largeInt $ \x -> uleb128 x == uleb128' x
+++ OK, passed 100 tests.
```

Another way would be to use `unfoldr` from `Data.List`, but that wouldn't be as clear.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer. And thanks for pointing out that my function didn't even works as intended!

Comment: @LucasJ: If possible, write a test. For example, you want the inverse (`uleb128Inverse :: [Word8] -> Integer`) to form an isomorphism for valid `[Word8]`s (`x >= 0 ==> uleb128inverse (uleb128 x) == x`).